# View log when installing

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, crash

Im attempting to setup a dual boot on a new Win10 machine via liveUSB.  I am following previous instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) but during the install I get continual stack dumps, and errors pertaining to NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU #x stuck for x seconds.. etc

I would like to post the message here or submit a bug report if needed but I dont know how to get to these logs on a new install.  Any suggestions you may have is appreciated.

UPDATE: I edited the install boot entry to include acpi=off nomodeset xforcevesa and it appears to be installing (not sure if this had anything to do with it), but as if now it appears to be working.

Comment: What do you mean by "new install"? Have you actually managed to install with no errors?

Comment: @terdon Thank you for the reply, looks like its installing, something I did get to work once before (with problem) but I guess we can close this particular problem.  Wish me luck and thanks again.